# Block access to url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I block users from viewing sites that are located in the folder of main domain? For example: main domain is www.maindomain.com. When I create subdomain for another account in cPanel, it creates folder it it is accesible if someone type for example www.maindomain.com/subdomain. I would like to block certain folders, but leave others, as I have pages in folder: wwwmaindomain/contact-us. How can I do that? Hope it's clear enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these rules in the htaccess file in your document root (for **maindomain.com**):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdomain1|subdomain2|subdomain3) - [L,F]
```

This will return a "403 Forbidden" if you try to access `/subdomain1`, `/subdomain2`, or `/subdomain3` from the maindomain.com host. If you don't want to return a 403, you can also redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdomain1|subdomain2|subdomain3) / [L,R=301]
```

This redirects any access to the subdomains from the maindomain.com host to the document root.

---

Rules to add to the top of htaccess files found in the **subdomain folders**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried the first one, where subdomains are blocked. It blocks the first one (subdomain1), but doesn't block the rest of them I've written after "|". Any ideas why?

Comment: I see now that it works for subdomain (folder) where is no .htaccess file inside it. Some subdomains have .htaccess file and blocking/ redirection doesn't work. Here what I got in those .htaccess files: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: I deleted content of .htaccess file in subdomain, uploaded to the server, then pasted it back in, uploaded and it works! I don't know why is it this way, probably it depends which .htaccess was uploaded last? Anyway, it works now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Roland I've added some rules to put in the top of htaccess files in your subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

Try following RewriteRule in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*) /index.php [R=403,NC,L]
```

This will redirect any /subdomain request to your index.php with forbidden response code

Answer (score 0):

very efficient way to do this is to place an blank index.php file the folders you do not want to show, so no need to mess with htaccess, or you can just create a new .htaccess with this code

```
deny from all
```

save this as .htaccess of that perticular folder you do not want to show to pubblic, however i perfer the first option.